# Why do the wormholes in Sliders always open in the same place

Tags: parallel-universe, sliders

In *Sliders*, Quinn Malory creates an absurdly benign wormhole. On travelling through it the characters wind up at approximately the same location in the other universe. They always seem to land where they want (usually the same spot on Earth), even though Earth is constantly moving very fast, and even though Earth is a tiny speck in an infinitely sprawling universe.

It seems especially odd in multiverse theory, where the parallel universe isn't necessarily layered on another universe in another dimension, but may be a physically separate location somewhere - how do they pin-point the location? Heck, how do they even set coordinates within our own universe?

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LNwhe_ztaGw&feature=youtu.be&list=PLIIOUpOge0Lv2jCm7LnYBiRYAPvxHyuWL&t=835) by Isaac Arthur is what inspired me to ask this question. He says:

> [Talking about the show Sliders] "*I don't remember what specific handwave they were using, if any, for why this always opened up on Earth and a close parallel of our society, rather than randomly dumped into space, or at a Big Bang...*"

Is there an explanation for this?

Comment: Typically, magic. But also, relativity.

Comment: @Dakacha I've edited the question to focus on one franchise as that seems to be the reason it has been closed for now. I've got an answer ready to go it it gets re-opened :)

Comment: @Jontia had that edit come up in review, I would've rejected it as changing the question too much. I agree that restricting the question to a single franchise might make sense, but why pick that one? And more importantly, it may not be what the OP had in mind.

Comment: Off topic for asking for a scientific solution? Show me a real-life wormhole and I'll agree with you.

Comment: @SQB, When making the edit I actually would have preferred for it to go to a review queue for that reason. That said, I picked the Sliders franchise because it was the first one mentioned by name, it's the one mentioned in the "it got me thinking" quote and the method of dimension change most closely matched that described in the "non-specific" sections.

Comment: Also, asking in general might work. An answer could point out how different (major) franchises have handled this and go over the different types of solution.

Comment: I've noticed that non-work specific questions don't tend to get to stick around. This meta-question about Steampunk sources seems to be the clearest reason. https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11932/why-was-this-question-about-steampunk-closed.  The Question here though is more "too broad" than "off topic". It seems those tags are overlapping, as per the meta question linked and related questions there.

Comment: Because of Quantum.

Comment: Unfortunately even though Jontia's answer below is the closest thing to the canon technobabble, they never did actually offer an explanation of why they wouldn't land in a new universe where Earth was 50,000km ahead in its orbit and die in space. I always liked to think it was luck. Ironically in The Guardian Arturo says: "Herbert Van Meer was a Dutch astrophysicist who postulated the idea of a parallel earth that was revolving around the sun at the same period of time, but spinning on its axis a little bit faster."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Sliders the technobable is that the geographic spectrum stabilisers ensure that the two ends of the wormhole end up in the same location. In Double Cross (S03:E02) Quinn's female double switches the names part of their two copies of the Timer device, making the gang's timer less stable for the future.
[Sliders Wika, Double Cross](http://sliders.wikia.com/wiki/Double_Cross)

> Quinn discovers that Logan switched the geographic spectrum stabilisers between their timer and her own. From this point on, they'll land anywhere in a 400 mile range between San Francisco and Los Angeles.

More generally and Out of Universe, this is an instance of minimal change. If you've invented a device that crosses dimensions, KISS (Keep it Simple Solution) means that crossing dimensions is all your device does. It doesn't move you in time, it doesn't move you in space, it crosses dimensions.

It is certainly possible for a writer to create a multi-verse where the "next dimension" over is set in a different physical orientation, or time flows at a different speed, but then your story is likely to be about something very different.

Comment: TBH I always felt it'd be better without the explanation. Quinn invented this thing accidentally in his basement after all. Would've fit much better with the narrative and the chaotic nature of sliding that it's just pure luck they never slide to a universe where Earth is in a different spot.

Comment: Remember the world where time flows backwards? https://earthprime.com/travelogue/reverse-world

Comment: Well, it's certainly a better explanation than the one _Quantum Leap_ used.